# How do I suppress the Microsoft Error Report dialog when a child process crashes

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a process with the  `System.Diagnostics.Process` object that sometimes crashes badly and Windows puts up the Send Error Report dialog. I have no control over the child process, but I'm already handling the case when it crashes, how do I prevent the dialog from poping up?

```
  Process p = new Process();
  p.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(avokeHome, @"bin\folderstx.exe");
  p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-f" + propertiesFile;
  p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => { if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data)) Console.WriteLine(e.Data); };
  p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => { if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data)) Console.WriteLine(e.Data); };
  p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
  p.Exited += (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine("Exited"); };
  p.Start();
  p.BeginErrorReadLine();
  p.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think its little difficult to achieve that. Reporting an error is user's choice (We set it via Control Panel -> Action Centre -> Problem Reporting Settings (Win 7))

Also. Check out [this article from MS Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841477) which talks about disabling this reporting (for all apps) with some registry entries.

Comment: This is unfortunate, but it was worth asking.

Comment: [WER Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638%28VS.85%29.aspx) also lists some registry keys, in particular the `DontShowUI`.